# mongoose - blogPost not a constructor error (schema/model error)

Tags: node.js, mongoose, schema

I am new to mongoose and mongodb, and I am trying to connect to mlab and insert some data, but I kept getting the following error for the codes below

```
var newPost = new blogPost({title:'First Post', post:'this is my first post'});
              ^

TypeError: blogPost is not a constructor
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\ipingou\website\hwnay\index2.js:39:15)
    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
    at Module.runMain (module.js:604:10)
    at run (bootstrap_node.js:394:7)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:149:9)
    at bootstrap_node.js:509:3
```

this is my code:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');    

var blogPost = mongoose.Schema({
        title : String,
        post : String
    });

mongoose.model('blogPost',blogPost, 'blogPost');

var newPost = new blogPost({title:'First Post', post:'this is my first post'});

newPost.save(function(err,newPost){
    if(err) return console.log(err);
    console.log(newPost);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a crucial part. So you have defined a schema, but you need to create a model from that schema:

```
var Post = mongoose.model('blogPost', blogPost);

var newPost = new Post({ title: 'First Post', post: 'this is my first post' });

newPost.save(function(err, newPost){
    if(err) {
      return console.log(err);
    }
    console.log(newPost);
});
```

You can find an example [here](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/schematypes.html). More detailed explanation can be found [here](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/models.html).

Comment: Thank you! That was it. I guess I should read the documentation more carefully. thx~!

Comment: I am glad to hear that. Could you please accept my answer as answer to your question?